# why docker containers in kuberntes Exit and restart every few Minutes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I just installed Kubernetes and configure Master and Node, the basic things is okay.

I can deploy deployments, pods, services, But, there is an issue.

1 - After few Minutes Docker Containers Exit and restart, So I can not access this deployments from External

2 - Master Does not assign Node IP to Services.

I do not what codes should I share here.

this is Sample Log of pod :

```
Name:           hostnames-64fbcd9c87-6khf4
Namespace:      default
Node:           164.132.1.86/164.132.1.86
Start Time:     Mon, 27 Aug 2018 15:41:59 -0400
Labels:         app=hostnames
                pod-template-hash=2096785743
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             172.30.53.7
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hostnames-64fbcd9c87
Containers:
hostnames:
Container ID:   docker://074ae800f3bbb81d31753b5eabc9c723bf2f49614fec884586ee3f7714664750
Image:          k8s.gcr.io/serve_hostname
Image ID:       docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/serve_hostname@sha256:07ab315083303397079209c526f6ed02f731d2fa7ffa0ad5c40b49410b105fee
Port:           9376/TCP
Host Port:      0/TCP
State:          Running
  Started:      Mon, 27 Aug 2018 15:42:04 -0400
Ready:          True
Restart Count:  0
Environment:    <none>
Mounts:         <none>
Conditions:
Type           Status
Initialized    True 
Ready          True 
PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:         <none>
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:          <none>
Type    Reason     Age   From                   Message
----    ------     ----  ----                   -------
Normal  Scheduled  9m    default-scheduler      Successfully assigned 
hostnames-64fbcd9c87-6khf4 to 164.132.1.86
Normal  Pulling    9m    kubelet, 164.132.1.86  pulling image 
"k8s.gcr.io/serve_hostname"
Normal  Pulled     9m    kubelet, 164.132.1.86  Successfully pulled 
image "k8s.gcr.io/serve_hostname"
Normal  Created    9m    kubelet, 164.132.1.86  Created container
Normal  Started    9m    kubelet, 164.132.1.86  Started container
```

I need help.

Comment: If your docker container exits, kubernetes will automatically restart it (assuming it's a deployment).  Make sure whatever docker command you are running doesn't exit.

Comment: You can gather more info on the reason by following the debugging steps in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/

Comment: @Doug I Just applied this : Kubectl create -f Dashboard/dashboard-controller.yaml , 
Kubectl create -f Dashboard/dashboard-service.yaml   and link : https://bitbucket.org/Dhyaniarun/kubernetes/src/bcc3c46179773691ae51c11785eb70bfca58ba9e/Dashboard/?at=master

Comment: Could you provide logs from your pod, You can find it using command:
`kubectl describe pod $podname`, in section events.

Comment: You can see Update above @NickRak

Comment: @RyanDawson I have issue in dns ==> nslookup hostnames : it does not return the right output it return  : Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find hostnames: NXDOMAIN

Comment: @Net Sim from you description all is fine there should be some error or explanation why it is restart and `Restart Count:  0` this pod does not restart.

Comment: if a dns issue best to go through https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ and then edit the issue to update with anything you learn